# AsyncTask Threading Rule - Can it really only be used once?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In the [documentation on AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) it gives the following as a rule related to threading:

> - The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

All this means is that you have to create a new instance of the class every time you want to use it, right? In other words, it must be done like this:

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url4, url5, url6);
```

Or conversely, you can NOT do the following:

```
DownloadFilesTask dfTask = new DownloadFilesTask();
dfTask.execute(url1, url2, url3);
dfTask.execute(url4, url5, url6);
```

Can someone verify this is an accurate interpretation?

I realize I pretty much just answered this for myself as I was typing this out... But it wasn't immediately obvious to me so I think this would be useful to have posted nonetheless.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

> Can someone verify this is an accurate
>   interpretation?

That is a very accurate interpretation.

Comment: Reading old SO questions and I find this extremely amusing answer. I laughed, and it was a whole lot.

Answer (score 7):

There is one more gotcha with AsyncTasks.
Please note that in the example

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url4, url5, url6);
```

executed on Android 3+ (API level 11, HONEYCOMB)
`url1` and `url4` ***will not*** be downloaded in parallel.
In particular, if contacting `url1` is going to time out, the transfer on `url4` will not even start until it times out. Unless you explicitly specify otherwise, all AsyncTasks are serviced by the same single worker thread.

The docs say:

**Order of execution**

*When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.*

*If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with* `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

Comment: However, please note that the question is on a completely different point - whether an instance of AsyncTask can be reused.