# Calling an AsyncTask twice behavior

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement a search bar that automatically searches as you type.

My idea is to have an `AsyncTask` which fetches the search data from the server, but I can't figure how exactly `AsyncTask` will behave with my use of it.

Let's say I have `SearchAsyncTask`.

Every time the text field is edited I will call

```
new SearchAsyncTask().execute(params);
```

So here's my question: what will the behavior of this be? Will I be starting many different threads which will all return and call `onPostExecute()`? Or will the first task called be stopped mid-task if another instance is called while it's still working? Or something totally different?

What if I write it this way?

```
SearchAsyncTask a = new SearchAsyncTask().execute(params);
...
a.execute(params2);
a.execute(params3);
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have implemented my app's search function in the same way. I use a `TextWatcher` to build search results as and when the user types. I keep a reference of my AsyncTask to achieve this. My AsyncTask declaration:

```
SearchTask mySearchTask = null;  // declared at the base level of my activity
```

Then, in the `TextWatcher`, on each character input, I do the following:

```
// s.toString() is the user input
if (s != null && !s.toString().equals("")) {

    // User has input some characters

    // check if the AsyncTask has not been initialised yet
    if (mySearchTask == null) {

        mySearchTask = new SearchTask(s.toString());

    } else {

        // AsyncTask is either running or has already finished, try cancel in any case
        mySearchTask.cancel(true);

        // prepare a new AsyncTask with the updated input            
        mySearchTask = new SearchTask(s.toString());

    }

    // execute the AsyncTask                
    mySearchTask.execute();

} else {

    // User has deleted the search string // Search box has the empty string "" now

    if (mySearchTask != null) {

        // cancel AsyncTask 
        mySearchTask.cancel(true);

    }

    // Clean up        

    // Clear the results list
    sResultsList.clear();

    // update the UI        
    sResultAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, I believe you could have found your answer on this site, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373826/execute-asynctask-several-times) for instance.
Basically, you can only execute a single instance of an AsyncTask once.
Trying to execute twice the same instance will raise an error.

edit : If you declare each time a `new SearchAsyncTask()`, you will receive numerous responses and call to `onPostExecute()`, but not necessarily in the right order. What would be best is to store the `AsyncTask` in a variable, and use the `.cancel()` method before starting a new one.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. In the first part of the question he is not executing the same instance. But it does answer the second question