# Best practice for repeated network tasks?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-networking

I have a small Android application in which I need to do some FTP stuff every couple of seconds.
After learning the hard way that running network stuff on the UI thread is something Android does not really like, I've come to this solution:

```
// This class gets declared inside my Activity
private class CheckFtpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... dummy) {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("CheckFtpTask");
        // Here I'll do the FTP stuff       
        ftpStuff();
        return null;
    }
}

// Member variables inside my activity
private Handler checkFtpHandler;
private Runnable checkFtpRunnable;

// I set up the task later in some of my Activitiy's method:
checkFtpHandler = new Handler();
checkFtpRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new CheckFtpTask().execute((Void[])null);
        checkFtpHandler.postDelayed(checkFtpRunnable, 5000);
    }
};
checkFtpRunnable.run();
```

Is this good practice to perform a recurring task that cannot run on the UI thread directly?
Furthermore, instead of creating a new AsyncTask object all the time by calling

```
new CheckFtpTask().execute((Void[])null);
```

would it be an option to create the `CheckFtpTask` object once and then reuse it?
Or will that give me side effects?

Thanks in advance,
Jens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would it be an option to create the CheckFtpTask object once and then reuse it? Or will that give me side effects?

No, there will be side-effects. [Quoting the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) Threading Rules:

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

You will just need to create a separate instance of the task each time you want to run it.

And I'm not sure why you need the `Runnable` or `Handler`. `AsyncTask` has methods that run on the `UI Thread` (all but `doInBackground()`, actually) if you need to update the `UI`.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648) if you need a callback to update the `UI` when the task has finished.

Comment: Why do I need the `Runnable` and the `Handler`? Good question. I thought it would be a good way to make the task recurring using the `postDelayed`.
Would it be better to call `Thread.sleep()` inside a loop in the `doInBackground()`?

Anyway, just as I'm writing this I found an error:
It does not make sense to call the `postDelayed()` in the `Runnable`.
If a task takes more than 5 seconds, a new one will be created before the old one finishes. This is not what I want so I moved the
`checkFtpHandler.postDelayed(checkFtpRunnable, 5000);` into the `onPostExecute()`of the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: The whole task (as by now!) does _nothing_ on the UI.
I've simply chosen the combination of `AsyncTask` plus `Runnable`/`Handler` because I need a _recurring_ task that is _not on the UI thread_ with the (later) option to do some UI stuff.
Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: You can call `Thread.sleep()` in the `doInBackground()`, say in a `for loop` or `while loop` to have it recurring.

Comment: But when I have an "inifinte loop" with `Thread.sleep()` in it I loose the ability to do UI stuff, right?

Comment: No, not at all. You can update the `UI` on any of the other `AsyncTask` methods like `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()`. `doInBackground()` is the only `AsyncTask` method which doesn't run on the `UI`

Comment: I don't get this, I guess...
When running in an infinte loop, neither `onPostExecute()`nor `onProgressUpdate()` do get called.
So how can I update the UI?

Comment: Which part don't you get and I will try to help?

Comment: `onPostExecute()` won't until you return a value from `doInBackground()`. But `onProgressUpdate()` will anytime you call `publishProgress()` from `doInBackground()`

Comment: You said that I can update the UI in the other methods.
But when I have an infinite loop in `doInBackground()`, the other methods (`onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()`) are never called, are they? Or is `onProgressUpdate()` in my example just not called because I created the class as `AsyncTask<Void, *Void*, Void>`?

Comment: Right, you have to give the second `param` the datatype that `onProgressUpdate()` will take and it will only be called when you call `publishProgress()`

Comment: Got it now. For some weird reason I thought that `onProgressUpdate()` should get called automatically, but of course you have to call `publishProgress()` for this to happen. :-)

Comment: So, from a resource-efficient approach, would you say that using only the `AsyncTask` in an infinite loop (with `Thread.sleep()`) is superior to my first version with the `Handler`/`Runnable`?

Comment: I don't know about "superior" but with `AsyncTask`, the others aren't generally needed or wanted

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new Async task for every call.

See the Android Documentation: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). According to this documentation:

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

Specifically check out the **threading rules** section. There is a similar answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18547396/2728623

Answer (score 0):

Java ThreadPools and the ExecutorFramework allows you to execute threads as needed and reduces thread creation overhead. [Check out the singleThreadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor). The thread pool usage is [pretty easy too!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)