# Android common async task with multiple callers

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have a common async task class that starts a tcp connection using my tcp client class. I am executing this async task while my main activity is launched and I define activity as caller. Here is my async class code:

```
public class CommonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Handler,String,String> {

    OnAsyncRequestComplete caller;
    Context context;
    String m;
    List<NameValuePair> parameters = null;
    ProgressDialog pDialog = null;
    public TCPClient client;

    public CommonAsyncTask(Activity a) {
        caller = (OnAsyncRequestComplete) a;
        context = a;
    }

    public interface OnAsyncRequestComplete {
        public void asyncResponse(String m);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Handler... params) {
        client = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                caller.asyncResponse(message);
            }
        });
        client.run();
        return null;
    }
}
```

When a message received I call `caller.asyncResponse(message)` and it runs in given activity. From main activity I start a new activity and I want to trigger `caller.asyncResponse` in this new activity and main activity simultaneously using the same async task class. If there are more then two activities I want to trigger that `caller.asyncResponse` in all activities. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it needs to be received in all Activity's then you'd probably want to use a broadcast instead of a callback.

Android docs for [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

And since you only want broadcasts within your app you'll also want to use it with the [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

[This tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) covers everything you'd need for this.

Sample
Add a BroadcastReceiver to each Activity like so

```
BroadcastReceiver rec = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //all events will be received here
            //get message
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        }
    };
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(rec, new IntentFilter("event"));
```

To send a Broadcast.
Instead of caller.asyncResponse(message);

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("event");
  // add data
  intent.putExtra("message", message);
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I am really confused about broadcast. Is it possible to trigger a method in activity using broadcast or localbroadcastmagener when a message received?

Comment: Thank you so much but the `onReceive` method is not triggered in activity after `sendBroadcast(intetn)` ran. What is the reason? Should I add a permission in androidmanisfest.xml?

Comment: no permissions are needed, just that the receiver is registered to the manager and that the event names are the same

Answer (score 0):

For some activitys, you can use Handlers. You need a handler by activity, then, you send a message to each handler and each activity will recive it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Async_Task extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>
{

    byte[] fileInByte;
    int req_no;
    boolean morefiles = false;
    String TAG = "Async_Task";

    private HttpHelper parsing;
    private MultipartEntity multipart;
    private File currentFileuploading = null;
    private Validations valid;
    private Context context;
    private Object obj;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private InternetSchedul internetStatus;
    private AudioSchedul recordingSchedul;
    int uploadtype = 0;

    public Async_Task(int Req_no, Context mContext)
    {
        this.req_no = Req_no;
        multipart = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        context = mContext;
        valid = new Validations(context);
        internetStatus = new InternetSchedul();
        recordingSchedul = new AudioSchedul();
    }

    public Async_Task(int Req_no, Context mContext, Object mObj)
    {
        this(Req_no, mContext);
        obj = mObj;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... urls)
    {

        String obj = "";
        parsing = new HttpHelper();
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF_APPDATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (req_no == Constant.REQ_AUTHENTICATION)
        {


        }
        else if (req_no == Constant.REQ_UPLOAD)
        {


        }
        else if (req_no == Constant.REQ_FORCE_STOP)
        {


        }

        return "";

    }

    public byte[] getFile(String type)
    {

        //return file in byte
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {

                if (obj instanceof GCMIntentService)
                {
                    ((GCMIntentService) obj).getApiResponse(req_no);
                }
                else if (obj instanceof Internet_SD_CheckService)
                {

                }
                else if (obj instanceof Activity_Audio)
                {
                    ((Activity_Audio) obj).getApiResponse(req_no, result);
                }


    }
}
```

**Calling**

```
if(valid.isOnline())
            new Async_Task(Constant.REQ_AUTHENTICATION, Activity_Audio.this, Activity_Audio.this).execute();
```

Or try below link if you want more functionality.

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-volley-library-example/

Comment: its kind of snipped for you... hope its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new `AsyncTask` for each call.

See the docs of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html),

### Threading rules

- *The goal of the AsyncTask is to take care of thread management for
  you and you should not worry about the threading mechanisms.*
- *The Android Platform handles the pool of threads to manage the
  asynchronous operations. AsyncTasks are like consumables. The task
  can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second
  execution is attempted.)*

Source: [should-you-create-new-async-tasks-for-every-different-call-or-use-the-same-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547304/should-you-create-new-async-tasks-for-every-different-call-or-use-the-same-one)