# Common Asynck task for multiple use

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

Can we create a common asynck task for multiple use.? If yes so please tell me, actually I am new in Android. Please explain how can we do the same.?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want a generic AsyncTask.Am i right

Comment: By using generic Asynck task, can we use one asynck task for multiple purpose..??

Comment: Yes you can do but you have to pass your parameters differently.

Comment: And you can call with one instance of AsyncTask once.

Comment: for Generic AsynTask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680546/want-to-create-a-generic-asynctask

Answer (score 1):

> Can we create a common asynck task for multiple use.?

- You should create a new AsncTask for each call.

`AsyncTask` instances can only be used one time.

Instead, just call your task like `new MyAsyncTask().execute("");`

### Threading rules

- *The goal of the AsyncTask is to take care of thread management for
  you and you should not worry about the threading mechanisms.*
- *The Android Platform handles the pool of threads to manage the
  asynchronous operations. AsyncTasks are like consumables.*
- *The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second
  execution is attempted.)*

Source: [should-you-create-new-async-tasks-for-every-different-call-or-use-the-same-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547304/should-you-create-new-async-tasks-for-every-different-call-or-use-the-same-one).

> By using generic Asynck task, can we use one asynck task for multiple
>   purpose..??

- yes, you can create a callback interface and just declare your method to do the task.
  Implement the method in other class and then reuse the method with any result you want to 
  send to that method.

Check this Post - [common-class-for-asynctask-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291490/common-class-for-asynctask-in-android).

Answer (score 1):

> Can we create a common asynck task for multiple use.?

it depends on what kinds of task you want to perform. If you want to:

- perform similar types of tasks which
- provides relatively similar result(s)

then you should use a common `AsyncTask` class.

If the results and functionality are different then you should create a new `AsyncTask` for such types of calls.

For example I needed to call a web service to obtain result in JSON then I created a common class (extends `AsyncTask` ) which took the target URL as parameter and returned `JSONObject`.

Here is the code

#### CallService.java

```
public class CallService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context context;
    ServiceCallback callback;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    List<BasicNameValuePair> data;

    public CallService(Context context, ServiceCallback back,List<BasicNameValuePair> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.callback = back;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(dialog==null || !dialog.isShowing())
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return CommonClass.getJSONFromUrl(params[0], data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        callback.callbackCall(result);
    }

}
```

#### ServiceCallback.java

```
public interface ServiceCallback {
    public void callbackCall(String response);
}
```

now when I have to call the service I use:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity implements ServiceCallback {

    @Override
    public void callbackCall(String response){
        //process and upate data
    }

}
```

Remember that you need to implement the interface `ServiceCallback` if you want to use the Common `AsyncTask` class in an Activity.

Now this is how I call the AsyncTask

```
List<BasicNameValuePair> values = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value1",value1));
values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value2",value2));
new CallService(Activity1.this, Activity1.this, values)
        .execute("http://www.example.com/someservice");
```

Comment: Yes it is for similar tasks...please explain how can I do this..?