# Android asyncTasks - can you call more than one?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Currently in my application, in one fragment (or adapter), I call more than one AsyncTask in order to gather required data for that fragment.

I am following this tutorial [link](https://learnandroidtoday.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/how-to-get-results-of-async-task/) to make sure that I do not block the UI while data is loading from server.

But since I call more than one AsyncTask in my fragments / adapters, I realized that this method will not work for me and I started to doubt if I am using AsyncTask correctly.

So, is it okay to call more than one AsyncTask in one fragment/adapter?

Comment: asynctask can be executed only once. if you want to start it several times you have to get new instance new MyAsinkTask().execute()   see this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373826/execute-asynctask-several-times

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke as many AsyncTasks as you want within reasonable limits.  Just be aware that AsyncTask behaves differently on different versions of Android, as documented in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) under the "Order of execution" heading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could, try with:

```
AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR();
```