# how to call if statement in async task?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-asynctask

Please help me it should call again the server if the response code is `204` how to call?

```
String command = ("http://api.railwayapi.com/live/train/" + m_train_Number + "/doj/" + m_year + m_month + m_day + "/apikey/tc9sc898/");
new JSONTask().execute(command);

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, LiveStationModel>
{
    LiveStationModel liveStationModel = null;
    protected LiveStationModel doInBackground(String... params) {
        IOException e;
        MalformedURLException e2;
        List<LiveStationModel> myList = null;
        Throwable th;
        JSONException e3;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            try {
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String str = "";
                while (true) {
                    str = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    if (str == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    buffer.append(str);
                }
```

Comment: This answer might help you...! http://stackoverflow.com/a/6374135/7316675

Answer (score 0):

your can check that it `onPostExecute` method like:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
     super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
     //check your if condition here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, LiveStationModel>
    {
    int resp;

                -------
                connection.connect();
                resp = connection.getResponseCode();
                --------
                    }
```

Now override onPostExecute like this,

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
     super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
     if(resp == 204)
{
     new JSONTask().execute(command);
}
else
{
//your code here
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the if condition in onPostExecute method of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

in your onPostExecute method check you are getting expected result or not, if not than again call your new JSONTask().execute(command);

like

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
     super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
   new JSONTask().execute(command);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check if the response is 204 or not but if you want to try another connection, `disconnect` current one and then make another connection with different url; because if you repeat your URL, you get the same results again and again(NO_CONTENT).

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, LiveStationModel>
{
    LiveStationModel liveStationModel = null;
    protected LiveStationModel doInBackground(String... params) {
        IOException e;
        MalformedURLException e2;
        List<LiveStationModel> myList = null;
        Throwable th;
        JSONException e3;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            if(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT)
            {
                //do what you gonna do
            }
```

if you want to repeat until you get the content 
use a loop like this:

```
    try {

        int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        while(code == 204)
        {

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[?]).openConnection();   // Different Parameter here
            connection.connect();

            ....

        }
```