# Use one instance of AsyncTask throughout Activity

Tags: android-asynctask

I have a number of `AsyncTask` set up as individual classes. I reuse them throughout my app. I wonder, in places where the same `AsyncTask` may be needed more than one is it possible to use one instance of that custom `AsyncTask` class multiple times? This is really a cosmetic problem since it bothers me having redundant sections of code, especially when an `AsyncTask` uses a callback to communicate with it's starting activity.

I've tried to do it this way -

```
MyTask task = new MyTask(new someCallBackListener){

    @Override
    public void taskDone(boolean youDone){

    }
});
```

And then in my activity just calling

```
task.execute(params);
```

This seems to work the first time, but I cannot execute it more than once. Do I really just need to initialize a new task each time I want to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asynctask can be executed only once as per the android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)(section Threading rules)which says

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a
>   second execution is attempted.)

So its not possible to reuse an AsyncTask instance. Further [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711183/asynctask-threading-rule-can-it-really-only-be-used-once) SO link would help you!

Comment: That's annoying. Any known work around or should I just suck it up.

Comment: @Rarw I can not say that there isn't any work around.But I cant think of any since the android documentation says so...

Answer (score 1):

While you can't use twice the same instance I think you could reuse the callback implementation by creating the instance this way

```
new MyTask(this).execute(params);
```

and implementing the callback in the Activity or the Fragment like this

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements MyTask.someCallBackListener {

    //All the Activity code

    public void taskDone(boolean youDone) {

    }
}
```

This way, you can create multiple instances of your AsyncTask without those redundant sections of code that bother you.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I'm going to look into that.

Comment: I have done this and it works... but now i have a button in the same activity and I tried to create another instance... but even if i reused teh same one... this still happens... in your example taskDone, what if you wanted a specific instruction to happen on the first use but a different set on the 2nd? So for ex:  first time I need it to save the value requested... the 2nd time I need it to save a file. I have the same setup, an interface using a method that I use in teh activity, but its still the same method, i need a different one called back. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You could have a counter or a boolean in the callback, and use it to know what task you have to perform with a switch or a if/else structure